# Create a Progressive Sum Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to display progressive_total using mysql.

I have a table look like this:

```
id    value                    cumulative_total
 1    100                            100
 2    150                            250
 3    200                            450 
 4    300                            750
```

I want to add a new column called progressive_total, so the table would look like this:

```
id    value          Progressive_total          cumulative_total
 1    100                 -                          100
 2    150                100                         250
 3    200                250                         450 
 4    300                450                         750
```

I use the below mysql query to display the Cumulative total:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value,
  (SELECT SUM(x.value) FROM house_details x WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS cumulative_total
FROM house_details t
WHERE t.income IS NOT NULL AND t.income!= '' AND YEAR(t.cdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY t.id
```

The above query works fine and getting cumulative_total. But i want to display progressive_total also, like i have given in the example.

Comment: Well, I know you want to display the `progressive_total` value, but as the `cumulative_total` value in your query, it is been calculated with some logic, so how about `progressive_total`? And if you post the expected example based on your sample data, it will help better.

Comment: Add another subquery like this? `COALEACE((SELECT SUM(x.value) FROM house_details x WHERE x.id < t.id), '-') AS progressive_total`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id, t.value,
  IFNULL((SELECT SUM(x.value) FROM house_details x WHERE x.id < t.id), '-') AS progressive_total,
  (SELECT SUM(x.value) FROM house_details x WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS cumulative_total
FROM house_details t
WHERE t.income IS NOT NULL AND t.income!= '' AND YEAR(t.cdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables:

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, 
       @s := @s +IF(@temp := @prev, 
                   IF(@prev := t.value, @temp, @temp),
                   IF(@prev := t.value, @temp, @temp)) AS progressive_total,
      (SELECT SUM(x.value) 
       FROM house_details x 
       WHERE x.id <= t.id) AS cumulative_total 
FROM house_details t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0, @prev := 0, @temp := 0) AS v
WHERE t.income IS NOT NULL and t.income!= '' AND 
      YEAR(t.cdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
order by t.id
```

Variable `@prev` is set to the `value` of the immediately preceding row. We have to use an intermediate variable like `@temp`, to hold the value of `@prev`, before `@prev` is set to its new value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/977db/6)

**Edit:** The above query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT id, value,
       @ps := @ps + prev AS progressive_total,
       @cs := @cs + value AS cumulative_total
FROM (       
   SELECT t.id, t.value,        
          IF(@temp := @prev, 
                 IF(@prev := t.value, @temp, @temp),
                 IF(@prev := t.value, @temp, @temp)) AS prev
   FROM house_details t 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0, @prev := 0, @temp := 0) AS v
   WHERE t.income IS NOT NULL and t.income!= '' AND 
         YEAR(t.cdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
   ORDER BY t.id) AS x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ps := 0, @cs := 0) AS u
ORDER BY id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/977db/11)

Comment: Definitely the right idea- but isn't there more query than strictly necessary here?